# Unable to Anchor UIImageVIew in UICollectionViewCell (programmatically)

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

Working on specing out a view in Playground and can't seem to figure out why UIIMageView is being placed in the center of a UICollectionViewCell.

Relevant Code:

```
class BookCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "bookCell"
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        self.backgroundColor = .brown
        addAllSubviews()
        addAllConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    lazy var cover: UIImageView = {
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var largeImage = UIImage(named: "medium.jpg")
        imageview.image = largeImage
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        //imageview.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return imageview
    }()
    
    func coverConstraints(){
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cover.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            
            /**widthConstraint*/
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: cover,
                               attribute: .width,
                               relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: self,
                               attribute: .width,
                               multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),

            /**heightConstraint*/
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: cover,
                               attribute: .height,
                               relatedBy: .equal,
                               toItem: self,
                               attribute: .height,
                               multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0.0)
        ])
    }
    
    
    let wordLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "test"
        return label
    }()
    
    func wordLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            wordLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            wordLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            wordLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cover.bottomAnchor, constant: 2)
        ])
    }

    // MARK: - Add Subviews
    func addAllSubviews() {
        self.addSubview(cover)
        self.addSubview(wordLabel)
    }
    
    // MARK: - SubViews Constraints
    func addAllConstraints() {
        coverConstraints()
        wordLabelConstraints()
    }
}
```

`BookCell` is then used in a UICollectionViewController like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = ColumnFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .blue
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cv
    }()

    var data: [Int] = Array(0..<10)

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(BookCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:     BookCell.identifier)
        self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**I noticed that using** `scaleToFill` instead of `scaleAspectFit` results in image covering the entire width of the cell. The result (see image below) fits what I am aiming for but ... see question below
[image]

**Question:**

1. Is using `scaleToFill` the only way to pin an image to the edges (leading and trailing) of UICollectionViewCell. If so, why is this?
2. I also tried adding the UIImageView to a UIStackView and I believe I got the same results.
3. Please note that I am not interested in doing this via Storyboard.

Thank you for providing feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more option: `.scaleAspectFill` but may be cropped your image's content.

```
The option to scale the content to fill the size of the view.
Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.
```

Think about getting the image size ratio (width/height), you having a fixed width based on superview, and height will be based on the image Ratio.